# Resizing KineticJS stage

Tags: html, maps, kineticjs

I created markers with custom html for my bing map (doesn't matter if is was google maps). The new marker contains kinetic js stage that contains layers interactive to the user. everything is working just fine except that now I want to resize my marker when my map zooms out or in. I want to give my marker max and min sizes and it should change it's size when map is zoomed in or out.

I'm not getting any idea how I can resize my kineticjs canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you should be able to handle that by simply changing the scale of the stage.

```
stage.scale({x: newXScale, y: newYScale})
```

http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Stage.html#scale

Comment: I've added the stage for each pushpin  as `pin['stage'] = stage;` and later looping through all my pins to resize the stage. it's working now but often too slow.

I think, to make it more efficient; I need to resize only
- those pins that are visible in current map view
- those pins that are not resized already.

Comment: @Sadi it's hard to say without knowing more about your application... but I think having many stages is generally not ideal.  Modifying only the visible ones would definitely help. Ignore any invisible ones until they become visible and then resize them at that moment.

Comment: Thanks @Greg I will try doing it. If you any other information on getting only those pins that's visible, let me know please. I have accepted your answer, as the main issue is resolved already. Thanks very much.